# JFrame Layout Adding

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, jslider

```
private void initGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(displaySystem);
    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton button = new JButton("Press me ");
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0, 100, 10);
    frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    synchronized(cells){
            reset();
    }
        }            
    });
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the code I have currently and I want to add 3 sliders right under the Button and I can't seem to be able to do it with BorderLayout. If I do `frame.add(slider,BorderLayout.SOUTH)` right after `frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH)`, it causes the button to be covered up. Is there a method for me to just continuously keep placing with in the south area and all the buttons/sliders having the same width as the frame?

Answer (score 0):

Use Swing BoxLayout.
Please see the below code:

```
private void initGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(createRootPanel());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel createRootPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JButton button = new JButton("Press me ");
    JSlider slider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 10);
    JSlider slider2 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 10);
    JSlider slider3 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 10);

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
    panel.add(slider1);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
    panel.add(slider2);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
    panel.add(slider3);

    return panel;
}
```